# How to add string from for loop with end = "" command, Python 3

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm creating a ADFGX cipher for a school project. ADFGX is the cipher the Germans the Hungarians used during World War 1. I want to know how I can add the random.choice so it gives the key letter added from the for loop. The end result I want:

```
key = 'advbfgdfsdfsjhfusdfasfdjhjhfjsf' // this should be 25 letters long
```

Here's my code:

```
from random import choice
def Cipher(keyword):
    alphabet = [
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
        "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
        "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
        "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
        "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
        ]
    for i in range (25):
        key = random.choice(alphabet)
    print("Your key is: ", end = str(key))
```

Comment: I've no idea what you expected from this code, or why.

Comment: Why are you using `end`? If you need 25 long key, you already have it in `key` variable, just print: `print('Your key is:', key)`

Comment: I was just wondering if I needed to put a new variable in the for loop so it adds everything together so I get 25 random lowercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to redefine the alphabet:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
>>> print(alphabet)
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>>>
```

To answer your actual question, you'll want to append the randomly chosen letter to `key` each iteration, rather than replacing `key` with a new letter each time. That being said, `random.choices` would probably be cuter than a for-loop:

```
>>> key = "".join(random.choices(alphabet, k=25))
>>> key
'utjgvcwsyzqxyoudxggkyrymt'
>>>
```

Comment: This worked also do I say which one worked or is it rude like saying thank you I don't want to take up space

Comment: Also would I be able to use indices with this like key[0] or no

Comment: It's all good. Yes, `key` in this case is a string, so you are able to access the individual characters using indices.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, it is not clear what you are asking though.

```
from random import choice
def Cipher(keyword):
    alphabet = [
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
        "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
        "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",
        "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
        "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
        ]
    my_str = ""
    for i in range(25):
        key = choice(alphabet)
        my_str += key
    print("Your key is:", my_str)

Cipher("")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want.

```
import string, random
key = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=25))
```